# New to Scripting. How to handle dynamic values in Loadrunner scripting for contents in the body from a web custom request function

Tags: performance, testing, scripting, loadrunner, vugen

In the below custom request, the body contents like "`trailerId\"\"TRL0000284\`",\"`masterReceiptId`\" keeps changing for every new requests. I couldnt find the response of the contents in the snapshot view to correlate. Please help. New to Scripting.

```
web_custom_request("assign",     
    "URL=https://,     
    "Method=PUT",     
    "TargetFrame=",     
    "Resource=0",     
    "Snapshot=t1.inf",     
    "Mode=HTML",     
    "Body={\"trailerNumber\":\{pTrailerNo}\",\"trailerId\":\"TRL0000284\",\"masterReceiptId\":\"1010899\",\"warehouseId\":\"3348\"}",
```

Comment: It is critical that you have some sort of tool training and mentor period.   Has your management allowed for this to happen?  Self-paced training with the downloadable course materials?  CBT? Instructor lead?  Who is your in-person (not asking questions in a public forum) mentor for tools, process, project work?

Comment: Can you tell me please why you chose HTTP/HTML protocol and not DevWeb or TruClient protocols?

Comment: If you have created this custom request by yourself (not a vugen generated request) than there'll be no snapshot. But you can anyways choose extended log (data returned by server) as an option to see the response and correlate accordingly.